# C# gridview row onclick

Tags: c#, gridview, onclick

I notice there is a "AutoGenerateSelectionButton" function but it's not really what I want. I want to be able to two things when a row is clicked (anywhere of the row):

1. change the color of that entire row.
2. get the value of a specific column and update another table accordingly.

How can I acheive that without writing client-side javascript functions?

Comment: Is this a webform or winform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a webform, you need to access SelectedIndexChanged event of the gridview using a codebehind file.

from here you can modify properties

```
 protected void ChangedRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.GridView1.SelectedRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
....
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The data is generated from a SQLDataSource.
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.GridView1.SelectedRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

Comment: And I did not enable "AutoGenerateSelectionButton". I want the user to be able to click anywhere on the row instead of the "Select" column in the front.

Comment: Are you using a direct data connection are you creating a model that binds to the grid?

Comment: I'm using a direct data connection by specifying the data source directly from the SqlDataSource that I created.

Comment: @Yang I had this same problem a few months ago. Will try and look through my archives to find the solution.

Comment: @Yang my problem was with UltraGrid (3rd party) From what I can see the Microsoft grid view doesn't have an easy way to access the selected cell.  If i don't fall to straight to sleep when I get home I will try and see if i can help more.